# @Column and @Enumerated doesn't work in embeded entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have main entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "partners")
public class Partner {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "external_login",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "partner_id")
    )
    private List<ExternalLogin> externalLogins;
...
}
```

And ExternalLogin is embeded entity

```
@Embeddable
public class ExternalLogin {
    @Column(name = "type")
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private ExternalLoginType type;
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "password_value")
    private String passwordValue;
}

public enum ExternalLoginType {
    ABC;
}
```

`@Column` and `@Enumerated` not works in `ExternalLogin` entity.

For example in query will be `external_login.passwordValue` instead of `external_login.password_value`.

`@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)` doesn't work too. Hibernate is trying to get `int` value of filed instead `string`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post exception/error details too.

Comment: Column name mapping is wrong and i get common error in oracle java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904
ResultSet.getInt(type4_18_0_) is calling when hibernate is trying to parse type column

Comment: Please post `ExternalLoginType` too.

Comment: added in question

Comment: Can you add `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` first and on next `@Column(name = "type")` and see whether that removes the error?

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163924/discussion-between-yegor-babarykin-and-rahul-raj).

Answer (score 1):

You misuse annotation *@Embeddable*. See description in oracle docs https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html

> Defines a class whose instances are stored as an intrinsic part of an owning entity and share the identity of the entity. Each of the persistent properties or fields of the embedded object is mapped to the database table for the entit

*@Embeddable* annotation makes sense only for singular assotiation fields. Annotating list fields as *@Embeddable* is wrong.

Just replace

```
@Embeddable
public class ExternalLogin {
```

to

```
@Entity
public class ExternalLogin {
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue just now.
The solution for me ended up being adding

```
@Access(FIELD)
```

To the Embeddable object.